# Error loading Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, macos, pry

I have just installed Sierra on my Mac and I wasn't sure if I needed to reinstall Ruby and Ruby Gem. When I put the following in my terminal `gem install pry` I get the following `Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/katypatterson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle (LoadError)enter code here`

When I go to irb I get this error message `Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.
You may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.io/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries.`I don't know if this might have something to do with it.

Comment: Looks like you need to rebuild a dependent gem that uses OpenSSL.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: What does `rvm requirements` say? Alternately, just start fresh: `rvm get stable`,
`rvm reinstall 2.0.0`

Comment: `It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/katypatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/psych.bundle
`

Comment: yeah, i would just `rvm reinstall [version you want]`

Comment: When you upgrade your OS sometimes it's a good idea to `rvm implode` and start over fresh with `rvm install` for the versions you actually need. This cleans out a lot of junk you may have accumulated over the years.

Comment: so I would type `ram reinstall 2.3.0` ?

Comment: Thanks meatspace. That worked.